# Orbit around arbitrary axis glsl

Tags: math, glsl

I am animating a simple circular orbit around a central object using GLSL.
2d orbit is simple enough, but when I try to get object orbiting in other axis it becomes more complicated.

```
float xVal = (radius) * sin(timeValue);
float yVal = (radius) * cos(timeValue);
float zVal = 0.;
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Rotation_matrix_from_axis_and_angle

Answer (score 0):

```
// n=(nx,ny,nz) is the rotation axis, if not normalized, use

norm = sqrt(nx*nx+ny*ny+nz*nz)
nx /= norm; ny /= norm; nz /= norm

// phi is the current rotation angle

c=cos(phi); s=sin(phi);

// rotation is most simple with quaternions

q = quaternion(c, s*nx, s*ny, s*nz)

rotated_vec = q.rotate(vec)
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  I'm still struggling to convert it into GLSL for my animation though